# Unable to switch window in Selenium web driver

Tags: java, javascript, html, selenium

I have the following homework:

> - Write a program using Selenium Webdriver
> - Open up the "parent.htm" file in Firefox.
> - Then click the "Open Modal Popup" button.
> - In the pop-up, click "Open Modal Popup" again.
> - Close all windows by clicking the Close buttons in the Pop-Ups

Code done till now:

```
import java.util.List;

import java.util.Set;



import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.JavascriptLibrary;



public class popup_test {

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{

parent();

}

public static void parent() throws InterruptedException{

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\jars\\chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

//WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("C:\\Users\\jain\\Desktop\\popup\\parent.htm");

Thread.sleep(1000);

String winHandleBefore1 = driver.getWindowHandle();

driver.findElement(By.id("OpenPopupButton")).click();

Set<String> winHandleColl_After = driver.getWindowHandles();

Object[] ObjHwndvals=winHandleColl_After.toArray();

Object Objhwnd=ObjHwndvals[1];

String strHwnd=(String) Objhwnd;

driver=driver.switchTo().window(strHwnd);

driver.findElement(By.id("OpenPopupButton")).click();



winHandleColl_After = driver.getWindowHandles();

ObjHwndvals=winHandleColl_After.toArray();

Object Objhwnd3=ObjHwndvals[2];

String strHwnd3=(String) Objhwnd;

driver.switchTo().window(strHwnd3).findElement(By.id("MyModalPopup")).click();

driver.switchTo().window(strHwnd).findElement(By.id("MyModalPopup")).click();

}
```

**Files**: Please save this as .htm extension 
parent:

```
<html>
<title>Parent Window</title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

   function openPopUpWithSize(theURL, title, heightInPX, widthInPX)
   {
   window.showModalDialog(theURL, title, 'dialogHeight=' + heightInPX + 'px;dialogWidth='+ widthInPX + 'px');
   }
</script>

<body>

<div>
<input type="button" id="OpenPopupButton" value="Open Modal Popup" onclick="openPopUpWithSize('child.htm', 'Simple Modal Popup Example', 400, 500);" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

child:

```
<html>
<title>Child Window</title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

  function openPopUpWithSize(theURL, title, heightInPX, widthInPX)
  {
    window.showModalDialog(theURL, title, 'dialogHeight=' + heightInPX + 'px;dialogWidth='+ widthInPX + 'px');
  }
  function closePopup() {
    window.close();
    return false;
  }

</script>

<body>

<div>
<input type="button" id="OpenPopupButton" value="Open Modal Popup" onclick="openPopUpWithSize('child.htm', 'Simple Modal Popup Example', 400, 500);" />

<input type="button" id="MyModalPopup" value="Close" onclick="closePopup();" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi what you want to do, after closing all pop up you want to switch your parent window. Am i right?

Comment: yes Naveen, this is exactly what I want

Comment: Than use [driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore1);] here "winHandleBefore1" string is containing parent window state.

Answer (score 0):

The method you have used showModalDialog() is specific to IE browser so better to try with IE browser.